# How to manage button state

Tags: servo

Extreme Newbie here ...I am using an Arduino Uno and a PCA9685 16 Ch. Driver board to control servos using a push button and LED feedback.  When I pust the button, the servo move but when I release the button, the servo move back to it original position.  What I would like to have happen is that when I push the button once, the servo moves and holds its position.  When I push the button again, return to its starting position.  Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Here is the sketch:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h>

Adafruit_PWMServoDriver pwm = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver();

int buttonPin0 = 2;   // Can add as many buttons as needed
int ledPin0C = 3;     // C designates Closed position of turnout
int ledPin0T = 4;     // T designates Thrown position of turnout
int buttonState0 = 0;

int buttonPin1 = 5;
int ledPin1C = 6;
int ledPin1T = 7;
int buttonState1 = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("pca9685_TurnoutFinal!");
    pwm.begin();
    pwm.setPWMFreq(60);
    delay(30);

    pinMode(ledPin0C, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin0T, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(buttonPin0, INPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin1C, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin1T, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(buttonPin1, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    ///////////
    buttonState0 = digitalRead(buttonPin0);
    if (buttonState0 == HIGH) {
        pwm.setPWM(0, 0, 370);
        digitalWrite(ledPin0T, LOW);
        digitalWrite(ledPin0C, HIGH);
    }
    else {
        pwm.setPWM(0, 0, 285);
        digitalWrite(ledPin0C, LOW);
        digitalWrite(ledPin0T, HIGH);
    }
    //////////
    buttonState1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1);
    if (buttonState1 == HIGH) {
        pwm.setPWM(1, 0, 370);
        digitalWrite(ledPin1T, LOW);
        digitalWrite(ledPin1C, HIGH);
    }
    else  {
        pwm.setPWM(1, 0, 285);
        digitalWrite(ledPin1C, LOW);
        digitalWrite(ledPin1T, HIGH);
    }
    //////////
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in loop is always running so when you release the button, the code sees this as digitalRead(btn) = HIGH.

You need a state variable to know where the motor is currently.  Something like this:

```
boolean state = false;
int oldButton = HIGH;

void loop() {
    delay(20); // enough to debounce very most buttons

    int newButton = digitalRead(buttonPin0);
    if (oldButton == HIGH && newButton == LOW) { // only when button changes from "released" to "pressed"
        state = !state;

        // tell the servo where to go
        if (state) {
            pwm.setPWM(0, 0, 370);
        } else {
            pwm.setPWM(0, 0, 285);
        }
    }
    oldButton = newButton;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ... I will try to figure out where it goes.

Comment: Also take button bouncing into account.

Comment: Michel would it be possible for you to elaborate on button bouncing?

Comment: Disregard Michel ... I did a little reading and now know what it is ... not sure if it will affect my project but again thank you for making me aware of it.